# ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug), gets stuck

Tags: 18.04, bios, acpi

My Ubuntu 18.04 is failing to boot and is displaying the following message.

```
ACPI BIOS ERROR (bug): Failure creating named object ... AE_ALREADY_EXISTS
```

...

```
Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! UUID=70269fa2-b15e-4014-b59b-9dcede085887 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

I have tried to add "nomodeset" in the grub but nothing changes. The recovery mode does not work either.

This have happened several times before. I solved it before by changing the driver after changing the grub permanently (adding the "nomodeset"). The problem now is that it gets stuck, and nothing seems to work.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution: I changed the SATA configuration to ACPI in BIOS and it worked.